# Humanoid silhouette on SpaceX's Starhopper; what does it represent?

Tags: spacex, identify-this-object, insignia, hopper

**update:** The silhouette now has a page in Wikimedia Commons: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hughmann_for_scale.svg

---

The images below are from a NASA Spaceflight forum [post](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=47120.msg1970940#msg1970940) and can be seen in @bolsachicagal's [twitter](https://twitter.com/bocachicagal?lang=en) and also in this NASASpaceFlight [tweet](https://twitter.com/NASASpaceflight/status/1154764428782592001).

**Question:** What does this silhouette of a bipedal individual designate? Is it related to [these SpaceX-related markings](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28424/12102) or this SpaceX [<s>Star</s>Grasshopper-related character](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/283032287602413568)?

[image]

**above:** cropped and zoomed from below; **below:** from a NASA Spaceflight forum [post](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=47120.msg1970940#msg1970940) and can be seen in @bolsachical's [twitter](https://twitter.com/bocachicagal?lang=en) *Click for full size*

[image: SpaceX Hopper @bolsachicagal] [image: SpaceX Hopper @bolsachicagal]

Comment: Only a guess, in [this picture](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/technology/2019/07/26/TELEMMGLPICT000204844009_trans_NvBQzQNjv4BqpVlberWd9EgFPZtcLiMQfy2dmClwgbjjulYfPTELibA.jpeg?imwidth=1400) the silhouette seems to be the same size as the guys below. So this drawing may be a way to feel the scale of the prototype.

Comment: @qqjkztd I like it! [This guy](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/283032287602413568) was also approximately "life-size", so two 1x scale human proxies on two different hoppers...

Comment: Clearly, it’s a kill marking. 

Comment: Whatever it means, as this is a reusable vehicle, it is likely that one will be added with each flight.

Comment: Just had to trace it..https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hughmann_for_scale.svg

Comment: @Ohsin that's excellent! I've added a link above and [here as well](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/216677/51174).

Answer (score 3):

SpaceX has a history of using dummies/models/mannequins on the test vehicles.

Grasshopper, the Falcon 9 landing test vehicle had a cowboy mannequin strapped on for test flights. But the bulked up landing legs, had room to mount a dummie. Starhopper less so, and has a more powerful engine (when running with 1 and 3 are coming).

The Tesla Roadster launched on the first Falcon Heavy flight had a mannequin in a spacesuit (Starman) in the drivers seat.

(Cheese wheel on the first Dragon as a further joke, etc).

This is just a continuation of the man in the loop testing they have been doing.

Comment: How is a picture on the hull ''man in the loop testing'?

Comment: @uhoh Right, but the point I was trying to make is they have a history of this sort of thing.  Just one in more in a chain of silly things they have done for fun.

Comment: also I don't understand the last sentence, if it's a space joke can you help me with context?

Comment: Less space jokes as much as geeks jokes.  HHGG in glove box, towel, Don't panic are all jokes, not space per se.  Cheese wheel is a Python joke.  Man in the loop is a joke I made about there is a man (iquin) involved in testing.

Comment: I like the idea of "human for scale" that was mentioned in the comments. Seems reasonable.